# PHP debugging tools in browser

Tags: php, flexbuilder

I'm developing a Flex application that make calls to PHP scripts. All work fine but sometimes and without any reason the app stops. It seems that something wrong in the call to the PHP script, bad response or simply there is no response and the app wait until such response.

My question is if anyone know how can I trace the response of a PHP script call within the browser. Is there any tool that can monitorize the call and response?

Thanks.

Comment: Try [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/) with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) both are FireFox Add-Ons.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script would have to die and report what's broken. This report would go to the browser and you can do whatever you want with it.

Read up on the following functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Or like Marc B said - XDebug will dump trace for you if have access to instalilng modules